# When do we have uniform directional derivatives of functions in Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, hilbert-spaces

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a map between Hilbert spaces. It has a directional derivative $f'$:

$$f(x+th)=f(x) + tf'(x)(h) + r(t)$$
where $f'$ is not necessarily linear, and $\frac{r(t)}{t} \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ (the remainder term).

So $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+th)-f(x) - tf'(x)(h) }{t} = 0$$
holds, but if it holds uniformly in $x \in S$, $S$ is some subset of $X$, then it is said to be uniformly directionally differentiable.

**I want to know**: if $f$ is directionally differentiable, are there any conditions on $f$ or $f'$ that guarantee uniform directionally differentiable? Assume $f$ is Hadamard differentiable if necessary.

In the case of real-valued functions, I recall something like continuity of $f'$ is enough, but here, I don't know.

Comment: You might be looking for [Fréchet differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative). In particular, a directionally differentiable function $f$ (more generally, a Gâteaux differentiable function $f$) is Fréchet differentiable at $x$ if the map $\mathrm{d}f : X\to \mathcal{L}(X, Y)$, $x\mapsto f'(x)$, is continuous at $x$.

Comment: @MichaelLee More than Frechet is needed I think since Frechet doesn't imply uniformity in $x$.

Comment: You're right, I misinterpreted your question. Fréchet differentiability would imply uniformity in $h$, not $x$. Let me think about this and get back to you.